# setting up different messages on making a booking according w.r.t chosen date and not accepting booking for the same day after a fixed time

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, python-datetime

i've all models and views ready for accepting bookings, i'm currently facing a major roadblock.

There are two cases in which i want to return a success/info message:

1: when a booking is initiated for same day i want to restrict same day booking time to 2:00 pm and when a booking is initiated after 2:00 pm i want give a message that booking will be treated for the next day.

2: whenever a booking is initiated for a future date irrelevant of the time a success message for the same should be displayed

for date-input i'm using datepicker.
and for time i have divided time slots and taken them into a choicefield.
each booking has a 90 minutes gap so options for the choicefield goes like this:

```
TIME_CHOICES = (
    ('10:00','10:00 to 11:30'),
    ('11:30','11:30 to 1:00'),
    ('13:00','1:00 to 2:30'),
    ('14:30','2:30 to 4:00'),
    ('16:00','4:00 to 5:30'),
    )

#form_field:
time_slot = forms.ChoiceField( choices=TIME_CHOICES, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control fc'}))
```

i've also tried something like this in my views:

```
booking_date=request.POST.get('booking_date') # datepicker.

curr_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
print(curr_time)
date = datetime.strptime(str(dt.datetime.now().date())+" "+str(curr_time),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
deadline_time = datetime.strptime(str(booking_date)+" "+'14:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print(date)
print(deadline_time)
if date >= deadline_time:
   messages.info(request,"MY_MESSAGE_1", extra_tags='alert')
   return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to='/home')
else:
   # other message 
   return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to='/home')
```

Comment: Frankly I would do this in your front-end (javascript), since the time slot choices also depend on the day the user picks. Then in your form, just check in your `clean()` method that the time slot and day are correct (to ensure someone doesn't submit wrong data bypassing your javascript). In your view you should hardly ever have to look at the raw `request.POST` data, first process the form and then check if the form is valid or not (`form.is_valid()`). And only use `form.cleaned_data.get('booking_date')` if you really need to access it in the view.

Comment: i also thought of this for once but then for intimating user about the booking treatment how to handle that as message can only be generated through views and if a 'js' approach is to be taken then how to do that i'm still unclear a bit on that part. 
clean method seems also good but still somehow i was not able to find what i did wrong when tried clean method earlier, by myself.

Comment: With js, you just don't offer the choice to the user: Let's say it's 21 August in the morning and the user wants to book a time slot on 21 August. With js, you can just disable all the time slots before 2pm. No need to show a message to the user. When the user selects 22 August, your js enables the time slots before 2pm. And if it's 3pm on 21 August, then you disable the 21 August in the list of possible dates. Again, no need to message the user.

Comment: Of course, since people who know a bit about programming would still be able to submit the form with the disabled timeslot (by hacking into the web page or using some form post tool), you still need to check if the form is valid as I mentioned in my first comment. If form.is_valid() your view redirects to the 'Yahay! Success!' page, if not, your view should returned the form with errors and display the error (no redirect).

Comment: yes i'm using form.is_valid(): , i just shared the problem area of  my code to make it brief, and thanks for the js approach i guess this would be the better option though i'll have to research about it (don't know much about js)
Thank you so much.